# Custom Field on Lead Mapped to Custom Field on Account

Tags: lookup, custom-field, account, leads

New Admin here, so forgive what is probably a simple solution.

On the Accounts Page Layout, I have a section called “Competitive Information” with four custom fields. I have been asked to make these fields appear on the Leads Page Layout. What is the best way to do this? My instinct is a VLOOKUP formula field which populates four identically named fields on Leads based on the Account Name. Does this even make sense? Am I over complicating this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best and easiest way is that create those "four" fields on your Lead object. Also do not look up any value on the Lead from Account.

Consider it this way: Leads always are first entry point in the Sales process, i.e., only when you convert a Lead, it converts into an Account. Now going forward, you can definitely convert another Lead to an existing Account, but if you see the flow from process perspective, you never have access to any of Account fields during the Lead's life cycle. This it does not really make sense to have any fields from Account to be displayed on Lead.

So when capturing a Lead (for an existing or a new account) you would still like to capture those fields during the Sales process and only transport those when you convert it to Account. And during the conversion process, you just map these fields to the same fields on Account.